# second statement of GAGA

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

GAGA theorem 2 states that:
If $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{G}$ are two coherent algebraic sheaves on X, every analytic homomoprhsim of $\mathscr{F}^h$ into $\mathscr{G}^h$ comes from a unique algebraic homomorphism of $\mathscr{F}$ into $\mathscr{G}$.

**What are the homomorphisms between $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{G}$?** Can we just take global sections of the sheaf $Hom_\mathcal{O}(\mathscr{F},\mathscr{G})$

see the main statement section of this article:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry_and_analytic_geometry

Comment: What is GAGA? The internet is large, and it can handle a lot of text. Abbreviate in the title if you must, but give us something complete or you are restricting the people who can respond to your question.

Comment: Try algebraic geometry gaga. But in fact gaga is a very well known abreviation for Serre's Geometry Algebraic Geometry Analytic. Now if only  I could figure out what EGA stands for.

Comment: "Very well known" is a highly subjective term, and might be considered condescending. If I google "sheaf theory" and "GAGA", I get this question first, so, if it doesn't come up in Google, on Wikipedia, it is not well known enough. @ReneSchipperus

Comment: EGA stand for "Elements of Algebraic Geometry" (when written out French).

Comment: I think your question has nothing to do with GAGA... it is just a general question about sheaf theory

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is a scheme over $\mathbb{C}$ then an algebraic homomorphism between $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-linear homomorphism of the sheaves $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ which is given by a compatible collection of homomorphisms between $\mathcal{G}(U)$ and $\mathcal{F}(U)$ (or if you wish, a natural transformation of the functors $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$).
Now there is a way of passing to the analytification of the sheaves (passing from $X$ to the complex valued points, holomorphics functions etc.). The GAGA theorem asks whether every homomorphism of ther analytification comes from an algebraic one, and in the case of sufficiently nice ones (coherent) answers this question by "yes".

n.B.: GAGA is standard terminology in algebraic geometry.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand why do you say that there may be more homomorphisms of sheaves than global section of the sheaf hom. The sheaf hom is defined to be $U\mapsto\operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal{F}_{|U},\mathcal{G}_{|U})$.

Comment: @Roland is right: $\operatorname {Hom}(\mathcal F,\mathcal G)=\Gamma(X,\mathcal {Hom}(\mathcal F,\mathcal G))$, by the very definition of $\mathcal {Hom}$

Comment: You are right, I deleted that.

Comment: Without some compactness assumption, this is not quite correct. For example, take $X=\mathbb{C}$ (or if you are finicky, $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$) and take the multiplication map $\exp(z):\mathcal{O}^h\to\mathcal{O}^h$, $a\mapsto \exp(z) a$. This does not come from an algebraic map.

Comment: Which statement do you mean?